# Links in html email becoming obfuscated

Tags: smtp, html-email

This has got me really stumped. I have html email campaigns which are sent to quite large lists. I use a service smtp.com and a program called Sendblaster.

The html is imported into the program then sent to lists of addresses, earlier today I sent one fine and saw the user behaviour showing which links were clicked. With this same html present it was sent to another list.

This time every link in the email, coded completely normally as far as I can see and which was received fine earlier is now coming through to people as malformed nonsense.

eg a link such as..

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/sales.html">Sales</a>
```

becomes..

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.comdJ4oS9KadbgwiFHknfSHfnjsiuOHn">Sales</a>
```

Every link is getting appended by random characters and i can see that these generated links are being clicked, what could be causing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: i think you'd have better luck asking sendblaster's tech support than stackoverflow for stuff like this.

Comment: Yeah I take your point, I was getting a bit desperate. It seemed to clear up anyway but I will chase up with them.

Comment: If you do get an answer, please either post it here (if it was something you were doing wrong), or close the question (if it was a temporary bug).

Comment: OK, I will sound like even more of a muppet now, but I can't see how to close my post !